# How can access the Question from its Course when using the E-learning module?

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7 and I have installed the "[E-learning](https://www.drupal.org/project/elearning)" module.

I have created these items:

- a Question.
- an Exercise (which includes the Question).
- a Unit (which includes an Exercise).
- a Course (which includes the Unit).

How can access the Question from the Course I have created?

Answer (score 0):

This module creates an hierarchical structure COURSE > UNIT > EXERCISE > QUESTION.

These are entity types connected with each other using an Entity Reference field. You can attach and reuse different units to each course, different exercises to each unit, etc.

So to access the Question from the Course, you follow the "links" that are created via the Entity Reference field. Obviously, for that you must first have entered the data (entity references) for each Question (and its related Exercise), and for each Exercise (and its related Unit), etc.

Comment: I cannot understand from where to follow the "links"..Should i call them from a VIew?? What kind of View (Courses- Course Results/Exercises- Exercise Results/Unit-Unit Results) shall i create??

Comment: Can you further EDIT your question to explain the access permissions you granted for the user that you're using? I.e. the various permissions as shown within the elearning_permission() function, located at http://cgit.drupalcode.org/elearning/tree/elearning.module#n113